# Java - Why is my final field null during object construction?

Tags: java, inheritance, nullpointerexception

I have two classes, one is abstract and the other extends the abstract class like so.

```
public abstract class ClassA {

    private Object object;

    public ClassA(Object object){
        this.object = object;
        initialize();
    }

    protected abstract void initialize();

}

public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    private final List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ClassB(Object object){
        super(object);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initialize(){
        objectList.clear();
        //objectList is showing null here when I call .clear() on it!
        //How is this possible?

        for(Object object : objectList){
            NPE!
        }

    }

}
```

I don't understand why/how ClassB.objectList in the example above is giving me a NullPointerException.

Comment: `final` fields have the default value (here `null`) before they are assigned. The problem is that you are calling an overridden method (`initialize`) from the constructor, which you should never do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, for this example, ClassB is a "proxy" object. That object i pass into my constructor is the real object used to populate the fields in the proxy. Do you have any suggestions how I could make this work?

Comment: Can't you just get rid of `initialize` and put the lines beginning `objectList.clear();` in the `ClassB` constructor after `super(object);`?